# Simple, pixel independent, CSS Grid resizing with no third party libraries

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I wanted to see if I could implement codepen-like or jsfiddle-like window resizing by using simple boxes and CSS grid without any third party libraries.

Live version can be found here:
https://codepen.io/Aquazi/pen/bYomRN?editors=0011

HTML, a simple div containing 3 divs:

```
<div class="container" id="topcontainer">
   <div class="box" id="box a">A</div>
   <div class="handler" id="tophandler"></div>
   <div class="box" id="box b">B</div>
 </div> <!-- closes the container-->
```

CSS,

```
body{
  margin: 0px;
}

.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2px 1fr;
    background-color: powderblue;
    height: 10em;
}

.handler{
   background-color: white;
}

.handler:hover{
  cursor: col-resize;
}
```

Javascript, the actual functionality:

```
/** creates variables out of interested DOM elements**/

var tophandler = document.getElementById("tophandler");
var topContainer = document.getElementById("topcontainer");

function allowResizing(){

    window.addEventListener(("mousemove"), mousePosition);
    /** adds the event listener tracking mousemovement and adjusting sizing of 
        the two boxes**/

    window.addEventListener(("mouseup"), disallowResizing);
    /** adds the event listener in charge of removing the previous event 
    listener so the event is not called each time "mousemove" is triggered on the 
    window saving unnecessary cpu calls**/
};


function mousePosition(){
   /** sets the new container grid sizing each time the mouse if moved following
       a mousedown on the handlder **/

    var fraction = Math.round(event.clientX*4000 / (window.innerWidth -2))/4000;
    /** takes the mouse position on the X axis and divides it the the window
        width minus the fixed width of the handler. The values is rounded
        after being multiplied by 4000 (to ensure little error on 4k screens)
        and divided again by 4000**/

    topContainer.style.gridTemplateColumns = fraction + "fr 2px " + (1-fraction) 
+ "fr";
    /** applies the desired styling on each mouse movement **/
};


function disallowResizing(){
  /** removes mousemove event listener **/
  window.removeEventListener(("mousemove"), mousePosition);
};


tophandler.addEventListener(("mousedown"), allowResizing);
/** When mouse is pressed on the handler allows Resizing of the boxes **/
```